# Migrate DataDynamics Reports to GrapeCity Active Reports9

Tags: activereports, grapecity

I am migrating an old project that used DataDynamics Reports to GrapeCity ActiveReports9.
In my project there exists a class named UserDesignerControl under the namespace
DataDynamics.Reports.Design.User
I cannot find which is the equivalent class and namespace in GrapeCity Active Reports 9

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DDR designer was merged into a single designer with the section designer. 
http://helpcentral.componentone.com/netHelp/AR9/arWLKCreatingABasicEndUserReportDesigner.html

hope this helps.